# If my blog on the side has no traffic is it still contributing to my home page rank?

Tags: blog, homepage, domain-authority

In other words, does my blog confer some domain authority to my website, despite the fact that it receives no traffic?

Note that my rank is very good, so I'm just trying to determine why.
My home page is by far my main source of traffic, and that's what I want.

If the answer was "no", then logically could I delete my blog without negatively affecting my rank? If "yes", then I can only improve things by continuing to blog and update that content, correct?

Comment: PageRank doesn't depend on traffic.  It depends on links.  Does your blog have any external links pointing to it?

Answer (score 3):

If by no traffic you mean no traffic from search engines you can delete it.

If its being spidered by engines but not receiving hits it might be contributing to your site by providing keywords (assuming its linked), although this is likely to be very minor if no one is actually finding and viewing your blog.

Comment: Thanks davidgo. It certainly is being spidered and indexed. My feeling is that the keyword benefit is useful for my domain authority. This was an answer from another forum: "In short, yes. Traffic is only one metric within Google’s while algorithm. There’s no way of knowing what weight Google puts on its value. Your blog is also contributing to your authority and trust metrics - so as long as it’s indexable and optimised it will be helping."